# logcat went wrong

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I don't know what I did, my logcat just changed, different from before. Now, when I wanna see log info, I can just go to Run, like this. These information is used to show in logcat.  What should I set to go back? Thank you in advance.

[image]

This is a macbook. How can I restart everything?

Answer (score 0):

In the top left corner you can see that you switchen from the normal LogCat to the Run console. In here you can see the actual outputs from your android app.

If you want to see the Logcat again, just click on LogCat in the bottom row. Android Studio will also automatically jump to the run window if you press play on your app.

Comment: Did this resolve your problem? If so please mark this as the ...